# Using 1 combo box as a lookup for another comb box on second sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 sheets, the first has 2 combo boxes the second has 3. I am making a macro button that will look at the Sheet1's combo boxes and basically v-lookup an select those fields in Sheet2's combo boxes.

Combo boxes on both sheets have the same drop downs items, but I do not want this to happen automatically (so not just linking the two).

I have found a number of posts for copying into the combo box (like code below), but not just sorting/selecting. Is this possible? If so any easy way to do it?

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").DropDowns("Boxname1").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E1")
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not want this to happen automatically"?  Is there a button click to make the second combobox populate or what?

Comment: Does it have to be vba? This should be doable with tables, named ranges, and data validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").DropDowns("Boxname2").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").DropDowns("Boxname1").Value
```

in the change macro.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something simple